# How to redirect to another page by pressing a button without selenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a web page

https://myeplanning.oxfordshire.gov.uk/Disclaimer?returnUrl=%2FSearch%2FAdvanced

that contain a **Accept** button. If I press the button it will be redirected to the another page

https://myeplanning.oxfordshire.gov.uk/Search/Advanced

I want to get the `redirected URL`, **without using** **selenium** that can be done using `scrapy`.

Can another give raw code to do.

Comment: scrape `<form action="https://myeplanning.oxfordshire.gov.uk/Search/Advanced"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `<button>` and `<button>` has to be in `<form>` which should have `action="URL"`

---

You have this `url` in

```
<form action="https://myeplanning.oxfordshire.gov.uk/Search/Advanced" method="post">
```

which you can scrape in `scrapy` (or `beautifulsoup`, `lxml`, etc.)